# Как поставить точку после strrev()?

Tags: c

Я переворачиваю слово, мне нужно поставить после него точку, то есть если
Ввод: Один
Вывод: нидО.
Я пробовал писать strcat(s, "."), но появляется ошибка, помогите поставить точку в конце перевернутого слова
(на skolkoslov не обращайте внимания, оттуда при вводе 1 слова всегда будет возвращаться 0)

```
int skolkoslov(char s[]) {
    char v[1000];
    int t = 0, i = 0, d, n = 1, a = 0, g = 0;//сначала считать слова, потом условие
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s) - 1; i++) { // подсчёт слов
        if ((((65 <= s[i]) && (s[i] <= 90)) || ((97 <= s[i]) && (s[i] <= 122))) || (('а' <= s[i]) && (s[i] <= 'я')) || (('A' <= s[i]) && (s[i] <= 'Я'))) {
            if ((((65 <= s[i + 1]) && (s[i + 1] <= 90)) || ((97 <= s[i + 1]) && (s[i + 1] <= 122))) || (('а' <= s[i + 1]) && (s[i + 1] <= 'я')) || (('A' <= s[i + 1]) && (s[i + 1] <= 'Я'))) {// Ищем длину слова
                d = 0;
            }
            else {
                t++;//если 1 слово, то здесь 1
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}

void slovo(char s[]) {
    _strrev(s);
    strcat_s(s, ".");
    puts(s);
}


void main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char s[1000];
    printf("Введите строку: ");
    gets_s(s);
    if (skolkoslov(s) == 0) {
        slovo(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Забыл библиотеки, #include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

Comment: Опять "доктор, у меня что-то болит, но это не ваше собачье дело, что именно! Ваше дело лечить!" Что вам доктор бы на это ответил? А сюда вы полагаете нормой прийти, не утрудившись даже прочтением вводной страницы сайта, и задавать вопросы, не прочтя хотя бы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking, и в частности, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или замените `strcat_s` на просто `strcat`, или указывайте допустимый размер массива, типа,

```
strcat_s(s,1000, ".");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, учту

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от вопроса; большое спасибо — на "птичке" там же.